# how does function has access to const before declaration?

Tags: javascript

I recently saw this questions:

```
function compareMembers(person1, person2 = person) {
  if (person1 !== person2) {
    console.log('Not the same!');
  } else {
    console.log('They are the same!');
  }
}

const person = { name: 'Lydia' };

compareMembers(person);
```

By seeing this, I am wondering how `person` can be the default value for `person2`.

`const` are not hoisted unlike `var`. And even if I try to do a `console.log(person)`

before function `compareMembers` I am getting Reference error.

IF any one can explain me how come the function has access to `person` as default value it would be really a great help.

Comment: `person2 = person` is evaluated when you call the function, not when you declare the function. It's the same reason why you can access `person` inside of the function body itself.

Comment: @NickParsons thanks, I was in assumption that JS will assign values to the function as soon as it sees the declaration, but seems like it not the case

Answer (score 2):

Your code will run like this:

- Stored variables to Stack (`compareMembers`, `person`). And referent to Heap Memory
- Stored object, function to Heap Memory (dynamic)

```
{ name: 'Lydia' }
```

and

```
function compareMembers(person1, person2 = person) {
  if (person1 !== person2) {
    console.log('Not the same!');
  } else {
    console.log('They are the same!');
  }
}
```

Then run `Call Stack`

1. compareMembers(person)

You can read [document of call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack) and [stack and heap memory](https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-memory-management/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, as you know, is applied line by line
In the first part, you came and created the function and did what you wanted inside

You take the first input from the user and the second input by default, if it does not work, you fill it with a variable

Now, in the next part, you created a variable, my friend, and you gave a function to this input, and this actually applies to both of your inputs, and this is absolutely true.

It only works in the opposite condition in your function if you give two inputs with different values

I hope I was able to help my friend